# Concurrency control while using gtk.TreeStore and gtk.ComboBox

Tags: events, concurrency, gtk, pygtk

I'm using two instances of gtk.TreeStore (in pyGTK 2.10) to create two drop-down menu ComboBox widgets; call them *device* and *command*.  The value selected in the *device* ComboBox will vary the values available in the *command* ComboBox. When a *command* selection is made, the combination of *device* and *command* selections are used to do more work (showing other possible parameters, etc.)

Something like this should normally happen:

1. Populate and set model of *device* widget
2. Connect *device* handler (for "changed" event)
3. Connect *command* handler (for "changed" event)
4. Show *device* widget
5. Show *command* widget
6. Wait for selection
7. Process *device* selection, clearing/populating the model of the *command* widget
8. Process *command* selection
9. Go to 6

Now, say in the middle of #8, the user is really fast and goes back to select another *device* and, before that second *device*-selection event can get handled, they select another *command* (populated from the initial *device* selection).  The second *command*-selection event is coming in with context that may no longer be valid after the second *device*-selection event is processed.

Is the best practice to do something like the following in *device*-selection processing:

1. Hide *command* widget
2. Clear event queue (by calling gtk.gdk.event_get() on all pending events, freeing as we go)
3. Clear *command* widget
4. [Re-]populate model of *command* widget
5. Show *command* widget

Or is there another more elegant way?  I mean, there's not some automatic event purging that can be forced to happen, right?

Comment: Even if you're making this application multi-threaded (and I wouldn't see why), event processing of the GUI would always commence on one (main) thread, and hence there should never be any concurrency problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to solve a non-existent issue.

You're right that it's theoretically possible for the next input event to be already waiting while you're still processing the last one. After all, those events come from the X process, which doesn't wait for you to handle the event. However, the state of your widgets is updated sequentially in your own main loop. That means that the next input event will be interpreted as if it happened after you changed the state of your widgets.

That means that if the user clicked somewhere in the top of your device widget while it shows the options for command 1, but while you're processing the change to command 2, it will eventually be interpreted by your loop as if the user clicked the topmost option corresponding to command 2.

If the user can click faster than you can process, it's her responsibility to know that her input may be interpreted different from what she intended. That is reasonable assuming that your processing doesn't block the application.

If it does, then I guess best practice would be to make the other widget insensitive while you repopulate it in another thread. I don't see why that would need any juggling/purging of events.

As a side note: since you say you're 'repopulating' the widget: have you considered just having several `GtkTreeModel`s for the commands and using `gtk_tree_view_set_model`?

Comment: Even if I make the other widget insensitive, I will potentially be repopulating the model... oh, huh.  The event is just telling me that something changed, and I have to go and say "what's the state of the world relative to the model as it exists right now", which, as I think @Ancurio is pointing out, must be a self-consistent world by the time I get around to processing the second event.